# JQuery Splitter: How can I split left panel by default on page loading

Tags: jquery, splitter

I am using JQuery Splitter splitter.js, And on loading the page, I want to split the left panel closed / splitted by default. On loading  a page I am not interested in showing left panel. How can I split left panel by default on page loading.

Answer (score 1):

from [docs](http://methvin.com/splitter/index.html)

> To make one of the panes initially
>   invisible, set its size to 0, e.g.
>   sizeLeft: 0 will put the splitbar at
>   the left side of the splitter and the
>   left pane will not be visible.

use

```
sizeLeft: 0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [this splitter plugin](http://methvin.com/splitter/index.html) (which was my first google hit), then the documentation should be helpful:

> Setting the initial splitbar position
>
> By default, the splitter gives the two
>   panes equal sizes. You can set the
>   initial position either in a style or
>   directly in the splitter options. For
>   example, sizeTop: true for a
>   horizontal splitter says to use the
>   height of the top pane (from the style
>   sheet or an inline style) as its
>   initial height. Pass a number instead
>   of a boolean, such as sizeLeft: 200 to
>   give the initial width/height of the
>   pane in pixels. To make one of the
>   panes initially invisible, set its
>   size to 0, e.g. sizeLeft: 0 will put
>   the splitbar at the left side of the
>   splitter and the left pane will not be
>   visible.
>
> Specifying the size of one pane also
>   tells the splitter to hold that pane
>   at its current size when the splitter
>   container is resized; any change will
>   be made to the other pane. However,
>   that pane may still have to be resized
>   to honor min/max height constraints
>   defined for the other pane.